# Matplotlib of plotting implicit function (Max{abs(x1),abs(x2)} <= 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, math

How can I use matplotlib to plot the function max{abs(x1),abs(x2)} <= 1 ?
The graph should be like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3maY.png)

I have really no idea.

Comment: What are `x1` and `x2`? Is `x1` meant to be `x`, and `x2` meant to be `y`?

Comment: I think it was not a good idea to mark this question a duplicate of the other one. `max(abs(x1), abs(x2)) <= 1` is not really an implicit equation; it's just a compact way of writing `abs(x1) <= 1 and abs(x2) <= 1`. Just simple linear bounds. A tool for implicit equations wouldn't be the right tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

A standard way to plot an implicit function uses:

- a fine grid of x and y positions in some range; this grid can be created by `np.meshgrid`
- a function `z` of `x` and `y`, e.g. `z = x**2 + y**2`
- `plt.contourf()` between two levels, e.g. between minus infinity and 1, to show the area
- `plt.contour()` with one level to draw one or more curves to indicate that level

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2, 2, 100), np.linspace(-2, 2, 100))
z = np.maximum(np.abs(x), np.abs(y))

plt.contourf(x, y, z, levels=[-np.inf, 1], colors=['skyblue'], alpha=0.3)
plt.contour(x, y, z, levels=[1], colors=['skyblue'])
plt.axis('equal')  # show squares undeformed
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plotting an implicit function]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a square from -1 to 1 in both axes, then you can do:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [-1, -1, 1, 1, -1]
y = [-1, 1, 1, -1, -1]

plt.plot(x, y)
```